# Change cursor when dragging in WPF

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop

I'm using this great drag/drop framework: http://code.google.com/p/gong-wpf-dragdrop/
I have two listboxes - A and B. When I drag from B to A, I want the mouse cursor to change as soon as the cursor is within the area of listbox A.

I've almost got it. By using the IDropTarget interface as follows:

```
void IDropTarget.DragOver(DragOver drag)
{
 drag.Effects = DragDropEffects.Copy | DragDropEffects.Move;

 // some logic to determine if hovering over listbox A
 // ...

 if (hoveringOverListA)
 {
  ListBoxA.Cursor =  ((FrameworkElement) Application.Current.Resources["ListboxACursor"]).Cursor;
 }
}
```

The only problem is, while I'm dragging over the cursor that shows is the the operation not allowed one (the black circle with the line through it). As soon as I release the mouse, then I see my ListboxACursor appear. So it's like it's a delayed reaction, like it's waiting for me to Drop instead of doing it while I'm DragOver'ing.

If anyone can see what is wrong with the code, I would greatly appreciate it. I have a feeling it might be to do with the DragDropEffects but it's mainly a hunch.

Comment: Did you set the `AllowDrop` flag on the control you are trying to drop onto?

Comment: I actually don't want to allow drop. The custom cursor I want to show is actually supposed to make it more obvious (than any of the default cursors) that the item needs to be dragged somewhere else.

Answer (score 12):

Answering this question because it's the top Google result.

```
protected override void OnGiveFeedback(System.Windows.GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
{
    Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Hand);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

This method should be defined on the drag source. It's critical that you flag the event as handled and that you DO NOT call `base.OnGiveFeedback`, as doing either will result in the default drag cursor overriding your changes.

Notice how I'm also using `Mouse.SetCursor` instead of the more obvious `FrameworkElement.Cursor`. The latter is a persistent property of the drag source element, and it's unlikely that you actually want to change

Answer (score 1):

That is because Windows tries to use its own cursor to ensure a default look&feel. You can avoid this by explicitely disabling the default cursor. See GiveFeedback event in this [tutorial](http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/winforms-using-custom-cursors-with-drag-drop)

```
 private void DragSource_GiveFeedback(object sender, GiveFeedbackEventArgs e)
 {
   e.UseDefaultCursors = e.Effect != DragDropEffects.Copy;
 }
```

Comment: Hi, I tried this but the problem persists. Is there any other way to forcibly override the cursor?

Comment: Hmm, I have no other idea. Sorry